# Can't load jqgrid in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I got the follow error:

> SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number  recruit.html;jsessionid=1f7j1qesicu7u, line 646 character 56

```
 var pagerPrevTD = $('<td>',  {class: "myPager"}), prevPagesIncluded = 0,
 pagerNextTD = $('<td>', { class: "myPager"}), nextPagesIncluded = 0,
 totalStyle = grid[0].p.pginput === false,
 startIndex = totalStyle? this.p.page-MAX_PAGERS*2: this.p.page-MAX_PAGERS;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you should replace `{class: "myPager"}` to

```
{"class": "myPager"}
```

because old version of Internet Explorer interpret `class` as reserved word which can't be used as property without be quoted.

You can rewrite `$('<td>',  {class: "myPager"})` to `$("<td>").addClass("myPager")` or to use just `$("<td class='myPager'></td>")`.